# Format date in Access Table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am a relative novice with Access and have very little experience with VBA code. A colleague of mine (sadly no longer with us) designed the database I am working with and I don't fully understand the way it has been set up (so apologies if I am a little vague...).

My problem is I have an Access Table which contains two different date formats: yyyy-mm-dd and dd-mm-yyyy within the same field. This is because we have two systems for recording officer time at different locations within our company which use different date formats. I have written a query which includes 'Between [Start Date] And [End Date]' as the criteria for the date field to query out a date range. This works fine for yyyy-mm-dd but does not work at all for dd-mm-yyyy format.

I have tried to set the default date format of the table to one format or the other but this table is continually updated by new time stats which are imported via a macro. Everytime the table is updated, the date format is reset. Is there a way of either hard coding the time format in the table / database or including a date format expression in the query to change dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd? Apologies if I have not provided enough detail. If you need more specifics I can provide them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Date should not stored in table as text. The best solution - change field data type to `Date/Time` and store dates in internal format. Date format for forms/reports will be used according regional settings of PC

Existing data can be converted to internal format once - manually or using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Either see to it that both systems upload data in the same format.
And / or change your macro so it converts all dates into one single format (you'd probably have to use VBA).
Next, convert all your dates in your table into one single date format.
And change the data type for your column into Date.